# On the Alexander-Hirschowitz theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I believe the Alexander-Hirschowitz theorem says that if we consider $P^r$ and $n$ points $p_1,\dots,p_n$ in it, there are "only so many" homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ on $P^r$ with values and derivatives specified at $p_1,\dots,p_n$ except for an explicit list of restrictions. In particular, if the degree is large enough, there are no exceptions. Is this correct?

I am interested in variations on this theorem. Suppose we consider instead of $\mathbb P^r$ another projective space $X$ (I am especially interested in spaces of the form $\mathbb P^r/G$ for $G$ a finite group acting linearly on $\mathbb P^r$) and a line bundle $\mathcal L$ on $X$. Is some version of Alexander-Hirschowitz known, especially if we specify just $1$ point and all partial derivatives at that point?

Comment: The A-H theorem doesn't say that you have "enough" polynomials, but that you have no more than expected.

Comment: Thanks, corrected!